# Why does Java give runtime error when depositing data into an array using a "for" loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I wanted to write code that reads a word stored as a String variable. The program should loop through each character in the word and update an array that contains the frequency with which each letter occurs.

The letters in the alphabet (A to Z) can be referenced by "freq[1]" to "freq[26]".

However, when I try to run my program, I get an error that says:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -64
    at ReadWords.main(ReadWords.java:17)

---

Here is the code I used:

```
public class ReadWords
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String line = "This is a line of text. That's not exciting";
        line = line.toLowerCase();
        int[] freq = new int[27];

        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
        {
            int letter = line.charAt(i) - 96;
            freq[letter]++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < freq.length - 1; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(freq[i]);  //prints all elements in the array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, obviously int letter = line.charAt(i) - 96; produces letter = -64. I'm not sure what is it supposed to mean...

Comment: @mikeyaworski Have added comments now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your error

Like rgettman said, you're including the spaces in your analysis of the frequence. Simply add an if-statement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
{
    int letter = line.charAt(i) - 96;
    if (letter > 0 && letter < 27) freq[letter]++;
}
```

`if (letter > 0 && letter < 27)` makes sure that the `char` that you're at in your `String` is in fact a letter from a - z

---

#### Helpful points

**Also**, in your second `for-loop`, it won't display the frequency of 'z', and it will display the frequency as position 0 in the array, which holds nothing (position 1 is 'a').

You need to change this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < freq.length - 1; i++)
```

to this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < freq.length; i++)
```

This way it includes element 27, which is `freq[26]`, which is where the 'z' frequency is. It also will ignore element 1, which is `freq[0]`. Try it. 
Or you could change the size of your `freq` array to 26, and subtract 97 from the `line.charAt(i)` and then change the `if-statement` I gave you in your first `for-loop` to 
`if (letter > -1 && letter < 26)`. And then use `for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++)`.

---

#### Display the letter with the frequency

Use this line of code to display the char corresponding to the frequency as well:

```
System.out.println((char)(i + 96) + ": " + freq[i]);
```

Or if you did what I said where you changed the size of the `freq` array and made the frequency of 'a' at position 0, use this line:

```
System.out.println((char)(i + 97) + ": " + freq[i]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are reading space characters (ASCII 32) with your letters.  Its value is `32`, and when you subtract `96`, you get `-64`, obviously not a valid array index.

I don't think you want to count spaces, so skip them; don't process them.

You'll want to skip other punctuation characters as well, with `'` being ASCII value 39, and `.` being ASCII value 46.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest way to do this would be to only check for lower case alphabets (97-122 ASCII values).

Below is the modified version of your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "This is a line of text. That's not exciting";
    line = line.toLowerCase();
    int[] freq = new int[27];

    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {

/*Only use lower case alphabets ranging from 97 to 122. 
The below if should omit all other unwanted characters from your string.*/

        if (line.charAt(i) > 96 
                && line.charAt(i) < 123) {

/* Subtract by 97 to start your array from 0 for a(value 97)*/

            int letter = line.charAt(i) - 97;
            freq[letter]++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < freq.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println((char)(i+97) + " : " + freq[i]); // prints all elements in the array
    }
}
```